# Pass Single Element to Method that Accepts a Collection

Tags: java, collections

There is a method that accepts a collection. I need to pass a single element to that method. What is the best way to do this? Which implementation of collection should I use?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`java.util.Collections.singleton()`

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you have a method like this:

```
public void someMethod(Collection c)
```

and you need to pass a single element to it(say MyObject).

There are two options here:

1. Create a List, add MyObject to it and then pass the List to method.
2. If possible, use polymorphism! - Create a new method with MyObject as parameter:

   public void someMethod(MyObject obj);